# how to get project id from infura

Tags: web3js

```
import { createAgent, IResolver } from '@veramo/core'

import { DIDResolverPlugin } from '@veramo/did-resolver'
import { getResolver as ethrDidResolver } from 'ethr-did-resolver'
import { getResolver as webDidResolver } from 'web-did-resolver'

// You will need to get a project ID from infura https://www.infura.io
const INFURA_PROJECT_ID = '<your PROJECT_ID here>'

export const agent = createAgent<IResolver>({
  plugins: [
    new DIDResolverPlugin({
      ...ethrDidResolver({ infuraProjectId: INFURA_PROJECT_ID }),
      ...webDidResolver(),
    }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Head over to https://app.infura.io/ and sign up, then create a project and get the project ID as well as the project secret.